# A novel about converging timelines

Tags: story-identification, novel, timeline

I remember reading a novel where multiple timelines converge over several days and then separate again. The character gradually becomes aware that the convergence is happening through a sequence of events (which I can't now recall).

In one scene, the lead character sees his own body (from another timeline) in the burnt-out, melted remains of his yacht. The action takes place in a coastal town with a harbour (hence the yacht). As far as I can recall this was not a time travel story.

He is re-united with his dead wife/lover but at the end

> the timelines separate again and he loses her and ends up with someone else.

I think I read this in the 1980s, I thought it was by someone like Bob Shaw, Roger Zelazny or Keith Laumer, and may have been a yellow Gollancz hardback. However I haven't had any luck finding it!

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  Nice question, but please make sure you come back and [edit] in any additional details you may think of.  For example, do you recall any of the other differences between timelines?  Why (in his timeline) did his lover die that she didn't die in another?  Any locations other than the yacht?

Comment: It's practically the story of my life.

Comment: Parts of this outline are similar to [The Other Now](https://gutenberg.org/ebooks/51112) by Murray Leinster.  In this story a man whose wife has been killed in a car accident starts to see signs of her presence around his house and realises that he is interacting with an alternate time line where he died in the car accident and she survived.

Comment: Just downloaded the Murray Leinster story - many thanks! I'll report back when I have read it!

Comment: Bob Shaw wrote The Two Timers, which is about a man trying to get his murdered wife back, but I don't think it has a yacht (just a lake) and it *is* a time-travel story.

Comment: I actually bought "The Two Timers" thinking it was this story - and you're right, it isn't the one I was thinking of. Quite good though.

Comment: It isn't the Murray Leinster story either :-(

Answer (score 9):

This could be [Dinosaur Beach](https://www.hachette.com.au/keith-laumer/dinosaur-beach) by Keith Laumer, which features a man who travels through time to correct the problems caused by other time travelers.

**In one scene, the lead character sees his own body (from another timeline) in the burnt-out remains of his yacht.**

In one scene in the Laumer book, the hero sees himself get killed on a pirate ship which is under attack.

**He is re-united with his dead wife/lover but at the end**

While undercover in the past he falls in love and is married, and longs to get back to her, but though it looks like it will work, things fall through, as I recall.

Comment: Thanks! I actually re-read this recently, and although there are some parallels, this isn't the book I was thinking of.

Comment: I hope someone else can identify your book - it sounds like something I'd like to read